# upload file from phonegap camera to .Net web api

Tags: angularjs, cordova, asp.net-web-api, phonegap-plugins

Server side

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        // Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form
        // data will be loaded.
        string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
            }

            // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Client side code, After I get the imageURI from camera send it to below

```
 function send(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    }
    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://localhost/api/api/upload"), win, fail, options);

}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    alert("upload error source " + error.source);
    alert("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

I get error code 1 on the fail function. is their anything wrong with server side code? can I send ImageURI the above web api i wrote?

Answer (score 0):

the code seemed to be working fine. The server user which was set on IIS did not have the proper permissions to do the write hence it was returning error. thanks

Comment: Hi Jaan, I tried this code however am getting a popup window that says

FileTransfer.upload

We seem to be missing some stuff :(

What is kinda cool though you can fill in the textarea to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute